# Pokemon Go - Google Fit settings for Adventure Sync

Tags: pokemon-go

On Android 11 and using a fitness app, does enabling "background location" on Google Fit affect Adventure Sync in any way?

Might it make counting steps more accurate/the app will count steps based on GPS location and not shakes/bumps, or doesn't it make any difference?

Comment: I let that enabled, and my Google Fit always worked pretty well. But I haven't played PoGo for 1 year, so I don't know if something has changed.

Comment: I see, I wasn't sure if it might drain my phone battery faster by doing so or if it makes it so that you get less steps.

Comment: Drain battery faster? Probably. But the game itself is a black hole, I had to purchase a power bank for every time I went outside for hours...